# Vuetify datatable with dynamic headers and content editing

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

In this exmaple at https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#content-editing I was trying to have a table where I get the headers from an api call and still have editable columns. For example my headers are

```
headers:[
    {text:'Header 1, value:1},
    {text:'Header 2, value:2},
    {text:'Header 3, value:3},
]
```

and each item has the properties

```
items:[
{
   1:[data],
   2:[data],
   3:[data]
}
```

The problem is mainly the v-slot of the template. I've tried this but it did not work.

```
 <template v-for="header in headers" v-slot:item[header.value]="props">
```

I want to pass the value property of a header into the v-slot instead of defining it like "item.name".

Comment: Have you tried `v-slot:item={headers, index}` and then `{{ row.item[headers[index].value] }}` ?

Comment: Can you clarify the question and provide a working snippet/demo? Do you mean like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/61425395/171456 OR https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873652/vuetify-datatable-enable-content-editing-on-all-columns/59883015#59883015

Comment: @Zim The 1st link's answer was what I was looking for. I got it to work after using the body slot. Thank you